# Windows Forms application that loads a tree from a database table, and displays it in a TreeView object?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, oledbconnection

This is the Code I have so far, I am having problem with the loop, I don't get it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication11_TreeView
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        OleDbConnection dbConn;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string connStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; DataSource=PartsTree.accdb";
            try
            {
                dbConn = new OleDbConnection(connStr);
                dbConn.Open();
                AddChildNodes(treeView1.Nodes, 0);
                dbConn.Close();
                dbConn.Dispose();
            }
            catch (OleDbException e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Exception!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Application.Exit();
            }
        }

        private void AddChildNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes, int parent)
        {
            string queryStr = "SELECT ID, parent_ID, description";
            queryStr += "FROM parts Where parent_ID";
            queryStr += (0 == parent ? "IS NULL;" : "=?");
            OleDbCommand dbCmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
            dbCmd.CommandText = queryStr;

            if (0 != parent)
            {
                OleDbParameter parameter = dbCmd.Parameters.Add("@InputParm", OleDbType.Integer);
                parameter.Value = parent;
            }

            using (OleDbDataReader rdr = dbCmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (rdr.Read())
                {

                }
                rdr.Close();
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Subhash: You can correct the formatting yourself, if you so choose. Use the "edit" link under the tags. Since you don't have very many rep points yet, your edit will have to be approved by the community first, before it takes effect. But you'll get +2 points for every edit you suggest that is improved.

Comment: You didn't tell us **what** the problem with the loop was. What exactly are you trying to do? What isn't working? What error message do you get?

Comment: First I want to select and add nodes whose parent node is null. Then as each node is added, call a function add its children too. Rinse and repeat. This technique takes many queries (and thus i think it isn't terribly efficient), but it might works.I  wish to use a technique called“recursion”, where a function calls itself. any help?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of a recursive method:

```
//Link this to the AfterCheck property
private void treeViewCheckedChange(Object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    TreeNode node = (TreeNode)e.Node;
    checkedNodes(node);
}

//Recursive method checks child, and then calls itself
private void checkedNodes(TreeNode parent)
{
    foreach (TreeNode child in parent.Nodes)
    {
        child.Checked = parent.Checked;
        checkedNodes(child);
    }
}
```